# .htacces url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php/apache website under my userdir, say `http://localhost/~johnny5/`

I have a `/en` folder with a `.htaccess` file and a `index.php` file :

```
/home/johnny5/public_html
                         /somefile.php
                         /someotherfile.php
                         /en/
                            .htacces
                            index.php
```

I enable url rewriting under `/en` so all the request are handled by index.php. here's the content of .htacces :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~johnny5/en
RewriteRule . index.php
```

### Up to here, everything works correctly.

When I hit, say, `http://localhost/~johnny5/en/foo/bar`, the request is handled by `/en/index.php`.

Now, for testing purpose, I move the site under `/var/www` so I can acces it directly by `http://localhost/`. I adjust the `.htaccess` file to remove the user folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I now have this structure:

```
/var/www
        /somefile.php
        /someotherfile.php
        /en/
            .htacces
            index.php
```

Now, if I hit `http://localhost/en/foo/bar`, I'd expect the request to be handled by `/en/index.php`, but all I got is a 404 not found for `/en/foo/bar`.

### It looks like the rewrite module works under my user dir, but not under the "main" dir.

I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that was all my error - misconfiguration.

I "AllowedOverride" under the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your new structure on server, but remember one very important ruler:
.htaccess rules works for CURRENT and CHILD (recursivly) directories only, not for dirs which are higher then .htaccess dir.

So if your .htaccess is now in:

```
/home/johnny5/public_html/en/.htaccess
```

it can't work with path

```
http://localhost/en/foo/bar
```

if your http://localhost/ root on server is home/

Try to move your htaccess to the root dir of your www server and try again

Comment: I moved the entire structure that was under `public_html` under `/var/www`. But I think my .htaccess is not execute at all, even if I allowed it in the config. Maybe something is wrong with the configuration

Comment: Damn, my bad, it was indeed a configuration error, I "AllowOverride" under the wrong folder. Shame on me. +1 for the help anyway ;)